# automatically posting on facebook with pagetab app

Tags: facebook

i have a facebook pagetab app this app is installted on pages where **i'm not the admin**.

Can i post on this pages with the app by using the facebook api.

Sorry for my bad english and thx for answers!

Comment: So you take advantage of your app's users to **spam** their page(s)? it's against the policy (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not the admin of the page, you can't publish to their page using your app! Since, to publish new posts on behalf of tat page, a **page access token** with `publish_actions` permission is required. (see more on this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#publish))

And to generate a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens), an admin of the page must grant an extended permission called `manage_pages`. Once this permission has been granted, you can retrieve the page access token using the following Graph API request:

`GET /{user-id}/accounts`

So only the admin could generate the page access token, and if you have that (of course with his perms :P), you can post on that page on its behalf!